# Android Studio ImageView not outputting image from URL using retrofit gson

Tags: java, android, bitmap, retrofit

I'm having trouble getting my image to output. I want to output the data from a API in a recycler view using retrofit and Gson. I've read through the documentation and some stackoverflow pages. I am not using a third party library (such as picasso) so I am using AsyncTask. The photo class is the typical POJO class, and I put the internet permission. Here is the code:

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    List<Photo> photos;
    ClickListener ClickListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Photo> photos, ClickListener ClickListener) {
        this.photos = photos;
        this.ClickListener = ClickListener;
    }

    interface ClickListener {
        void getItem(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_view, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view, ClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.title.setText(photos.get(position).title);
        holder.albumid.setText(photos.get(position).albumId);
        holder.regid.setText(photos.get(position).id);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                holder.circleImageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(photos.get(position).thumbnailUrl));
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(photos.get(position).url));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView title, albumid, regid;
        ImageView imageView;
        ClickListener ClickListener;
        CircleImageView circleImageView;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener ClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            albumid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumid);
            regid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            this.ClickListener = ClickListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClickListener.getItem(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            Log.e("src",src);
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.ClickListener {
        ApiInterface apiInterface;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        List<Photo> photos;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

            apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            apiInterface.getPhotos().enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
                    photos = response.body();
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(photos, MainActivity.this));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void getItem(int position) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(photos.get(position).title)
                    .setMessage(photos.get(position).url)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

**APIClient**

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**APIInterface**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/photos")
    Call<List<Photo>> getPhotos();

    @GET("/photos/{id}")
    Call<Photo> getPhoto(@Path("id") int id);

    @GET("/photos")
    Call<Photo> getPhotoUsingQuery(@Query("id") int id);
}
```

**Child View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/albumid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I should mention all the other info from the api displays correctly (title, id, and when i click on the box i get the correct url) just the picture doesn't show for some reason :(

Comment: Use Glide to display images directly from a url. Glide also handles caching.